# Why is socket on connect but `socket.connected` is false?

Tags: socket.io

From what I have read, `socket.on('connect')` means that the socket is connected already, right? But I found something strange with my socket. I feel like it is not connected, and that is why I do a `console.log` of
`socket.connected`, and what is shocking is that `socket.on('connect')` is triggered but `socket.connected` is `false`. It confuses me, what is actually happening? I use the latest flask-socketio on the server side, in case you are wondering, and the socket.io version is 4.0.

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
   console.log("Connected...!", socket.connected)
   });
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/), `connected` should be `true` inside the `connect` event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry for the late reply. Yes it should be and that is why I got confused